# Hibernate and mssql inner join rowcount

Tags: java, hibernate

I am struggling with Hibernate Criteria. My aim is to create the following request using Hibernate Criteria :

```
select
    count(*) as y0_ 
from
    PInterface this_ 
inner join
    Product product2_ 
        on this_.product_id=product2_.id 
where
    this_.product_interface_type_id=?
```

Here is my code:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "PInterface")
public class PInterface {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;
    @Column(name = "product_interface_type_id")
    private int type;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Product product;
}
@Entity @Table(name = "Product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

//Criteria is :
Object criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria(PInterface.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("type", 1))
                    .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
                    .uniqueResult()
                    ;
```

However, the results ...

```
select
    count(*) as y0_ 
from
    PInterface this_ 
where
    this_.product_interface_type_id=?
```

Where Inner join?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
           Object criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(PInterface.class)
                .createCriteria("product")
                .createAlias("product", "p")
                .add( Restrictions.eqProperty("p.id", "productId") )
                .add(Restrictions.eq("type", 1))
                .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
                .uniqueResult();
```